# ReplyingKafkaTemplate with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Is it possible to use `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` with Spring Cloud Stream? Is there any code example of a configuration in order to use it?

Comment: Do you want to use it within a `@StreamListener` or do you want to use it as a client with `@StreamListener` as the server?

Comment: Second option. I would like to publish a message that is processed by a `@StreamListener` in different service and wait for the response.

Answer (score 1):

This is all in one application but illustrates how it works...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class So57380643Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So57380643Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[], byte[]> replyer(ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> pf,
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]> replyContainer) {

        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, replyContainer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]> replyContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<byte[], byte[]> factory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]> container = factory.createContainer("replyTopic");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("replies.group");
        return container;
    }

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public String listen(String in) {
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[], byte[]> replyer) {
        return args -> {
            ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<>("requestTopic", "foo".getBytes());
            RequestReplyFuture<byte[], byte[], byte[]> future = replyer.sendAndReceive(record);
            RecordMetadata meta = future.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata();
            System.out.println(meta);
            ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecord = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println(new String(consumerRecord.value()));
        };
    }

}
```

and

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: requestTopic
          group: so57380643
        output:
          destination: replyTopic
```

result:

```
requestTopic-0@3
FOO
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell, I will try ASAP and let you know